# Screen brightness regarding

Tags: screen

I have sony vaio E series VPCEH28FN, ubuntu 16.02.I used to see brightness animation upon pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>,<kbd>F5</kbd> but not actual brightness of screen.It always show 100%. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem is a bug in the intel graphic driver,
first make sure to update everything so

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

update the `linux-headers-generic` and reboot, then open a terminal with <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keys.

the type

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and look for a line that says betweeen quotes `"quiet splash"`

just in the same spot add

```
acpi_backlight=video
```

so now looks like

```
"quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

with that done just save and exit and then write

```
sudo update-grub
```

with all of this done just reboot and you will be able to use the brightness keys

Comment: After adding this "quiet splash acpi_backlight=video" in which way i save this. I am a new user of ubuntu. Pls tell me the saving option.

Comment: @NURALAMMANDAL with CNTRL + X then hit double ENTER